# Views Load More for products listing page in ajax

Tags: views

For my **ecommerce website** i am using `View Infinite Scroll` module which is for Products listing page lazy loading,

Lazy loading works fine for my products listing view, but my requirement is when i click **View More** button then only it gets to load more products.

Is there options to call View More button or anyother modules supports for my requirement, please tell me if anyone have any idea means.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [views load more](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_load_more) module. It provides a button. Clicking that button lists more contents only. The pager should be defined in your views settings.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually really easy to do with standard Views and [jQuery.autopager](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-autopager/) in your theme.

The most important part is using the correct classes, I can't find my working example at the moment, but it should look something like:

```
$.autopager({
  // where contents would be appended.
  // use "appendTo" or "insertBefore"
  appendTo: '.views-content',

  // a selector that matches a element of next page link
  link: '.pagination .next a:first',

  // a selector that matches page contents
  content: '.views-row',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In views, there is option for

> Use AJAX

from advanced settings, there we can select **Yes**, then it will work Ajax view more